# How to get the entire class from a click when the listview is "instagram-designed"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So what i want to achieve is that when you click on an image i want the entire data for that class. So if look at the current example I have an image + a name (I intend to build upon this going forward).

I have also assigned a rowID for each item and binded it to its classid to somehow/someway work with that in order to retrieve the entire class of data.

My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="imagesListview">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <AbsoluteLayout>

                            <Button Image="{Binding theimage}" 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" Text = "{Binding thename}" 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" ClassId = "{Binding rowid}" Clicked = "OnImageTapped"/>

                           <Button Image="{Binding theimage2}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" Text = "{Binding thename2}"  
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" ClassId = "{Binding rowid}"  Clicked = "OnImageTapped"/>

                            <Button Image="{Binding theimage3}" 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Text = "{Binding thename3}"  ClassId = "{Binding rowid}" Clicked = "OnImageTapped"/>

                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

CODE:

```
public class info 
{
    public  string theimage {get; set;}
    public  string theimage2 {get; set;}
    public  string theimage3 {get; set;}

    public  string thename {get; set;}
    public  string thename2 {get; set;}
    public  string thename3 {get; set;}

    public  string rowid {get; set;}
}
```

How I load the images from my DB.

```
new List<info> imagesList = new List<info> ();

async void loadPhotos ()
{

    int ndx = 0;
    info Info = null;
    var getInfo = await phpApi.getPhotos ();

    imagesListview.ItemsSource = null;
    imagesList = new List<info> ();

    foreach (var items in getInfo["results"]) {

        if (ndx == 0) {
            Info = new info();
            Info.theimage = items ["Photo"].ToString();
            Info.rowid = "1";
            Info.thename = items ["Name"].ToString();
            ndx++;
        } else

            if (ndx == 1) {
                Info.theimage2 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
                Info.rowid = "2";
                Info.thename2 = items ["Name"].ToString();
                ndx++;
            } else

                if (ndx == 2) {
                    Info.theimage3 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
                    Info.rowid = "3";
                    Info.thename3 = items ["Name"].ToString();
                    imagesList.Add(Info);
                    Info = null;
                    ndx = 0;
                }
    }

    if (Info != null) {
        imagesList.Add(Info);
    }

    imagesListview.ItemsSource = imagesList;

}
```

The OnImageTapped function:

```
async void OnImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) { 

    /*Now I have a classid assigned to each image on 
    what row they actually are on, but I am unsure how to use this 
    and/or their is an approach where I can instead bind the whole class?
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your XAML, use the "." path when binding to bind the entire object

```
CommandParameter = "{Binding .}"
```

then in the event handler

```
async void OnImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) { 

   var button = (Button)sender;
   var item = (info)button.CommandParameter;
}
```